# How to dynamically route links in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter-3

I am working on a Blogging web. After creating a post, i am able to view it in the posts page. However, i have limited it to just 60 words by using the `word_limitter` and then there's a link **Read More** with the code below that should take me to a new page showing all the content  of the post.

```
<?php echo site_url('/posts/'.$post['slug']); ?>
```

Now, my challenge is dynamic routing, as in, i want it in such a way that whenever i click **Read More** on any any post, it just opens that specific post.
My controller function

```
public function view($slug = NULL){
    $data['post'] = $this->posts_model->get_posts($slug);
    $post_id = $data['post']['id'];
    $data['comments'] = $this->comments_model->get_comments($post_id);

    if(empty($data['post'])){
        show_404();
    }

    $data['title'] = $data['post']['title'];

    $this->load->view('template/header');
    $this->load->view('posts/readmore', $data);
    $this->load->view('template/footer');
}
```

and my model is here

```
 public function get_posts($slug=FALSE, $limit= FALSE, $offset =FALSE){
    if($limit){
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    }
    if($slug === FALSE){
        $this->db->order_by('posts.id', 'DESC');
        $this->db->join('categories', 'categories.id = posts.category_id');
        $query= $this->db->get('posts');
        return $query->result_array();

    }
    $query = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('slug' =>$slug));
    return $query->row_array();

}
```

This is how my route looks like

```
$route['posts/(:any)'] = 'posts/readmore/$1';
```

When i click on read more, it gives me a 404. when i remove the route above and click more, it shows blank page.

Comment: I believe your controller function should be named `readmore` instead of `view`. It should match the pattern on the right side of the route: the first part (posts) refers to the controller name, the second part (readmore) to the function name within that controller and the $1 refers the value to pass to that function.

Comment: sure, let me implement your suggestion.

Comment: done. it has now worked, thanks